# Как построить нейронную сеть, что бы она "предсказывала" относиться ли входной текст к как-либо категории или нет?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Моя текущая нейронная сеть может классифицировать входной текст по 3 категориям, проблема в том, что любой входной текст она в любом случаи (неважно относиться ли текст к какой-либо из 3 категорий) классифицирует к какой-либо категории.

Как построить нейронную сеть так, что бы она "предсказывала" относиться ли входной текст к как-либо категории или же нет, и только после этого относила его (тест) к какой-либо категории.

Comment: Отредактируйте заголовок так, что по нему была понятна суть вопроса. "Вопросов по нейронным сетям" очень много.

Comment: Добавить четвёртую категорию, которая будет означать что текст не относится ни к одной из категорий

Comment: @diraria как это релизовать на этпае обучения сети?

Comment: @Сергей Андреев -  Вам надо просто построить сеть с четырьмя категориям. Три из них - это ваши смысловые категории, четвертая - то что не попало в первые три.